# What is the name for the phenomenon of verb phrase being an argument of a predicate

Tags: syntax, terminology, parsing, verb-phrase

In the sentence

> He makes you want to leave early today to get more space for himself

instead of having NP as argument to the predicate "makes", we get an entire verb phrase "want to leave early today".

So we end up with a parse tree of VP := Verb + Object + Verb Phrase.

What is the terminology for this phenomenon?
Also, what will be the name for the Verb Phrase **want to leave early today**?
In all, what will be the correct parse tree for this sentence?

Comment: I haven't heard of a special term, it's just a verb phrase argument? I don't know why a special term would be needed or helpful.

Comment: First of all, wording it " ... + Object + Verb Phrase" is a bit misleading because the VP is just as much an object to the verb as the NP is, just of a different type (VP instead of NP). Then, the "correct parse tree" totally depends on what syntax theory assume - that already starts with the problem whether for ditransitive verbs (like this one) you assume ternary braching into V + Obj1 + Obj2 or want to stick to the binary principle (which is more often than not the preferred variant, but forces one to introduce lots of empty categories that you usually don't want in a pragmatic parse tree).

Comment: What do you mean by "what will be the name for the Verb Phrase *want to leave early today*"? This is simply a VP, which is an object of the ditransitive verb *make* in the sentence.

Comment: I don't think _make_ is ditransitive here. It just means _cause_ and takes an infinitive complement like _cause_, except _make_ takes an infinitive without _to_. Contrast _He caused you to want to leave_ with _He made you want to leave_. _Cause_ requires a _to_, _make_ in this sense does not allow it. Just an irregular verbal tic, that's all.

Comment: Oh, and as for the name, I'd say it was a reduced infinitive clause. English is full of the remains of deceased clauses; syntax is very like archaeology or geology that way.

Comment: I agree with jlawler, "make" isn't ditransitive in the sentence. The VP is a verbal complement (with a bare infinitive).

Comment: Study the terms 'control verb' and 'raising [to subject/object] verb'.  When drawing a tree, the object nodes of the controlling verbs ('make' and 'want') should be their controlled verbs ('want' and 'to leave'), and not the 'raised' object[s].

Comment: It's a typical catenative construction where "want to leave early today" is catenative complement of "make", and in turn "to leave early today" is catenative complement of "want". "You" is a 'raised' object and is syntactic object of the matrix verb "make".

Comment: @BillJ By "catenative" you mean "right-branching"? What does "catenative" oppose?

Comment: @amI And the classic name for "control" is "[Equi", short for _Equivalent Noun Phrase Deletion_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), also contrasted with Raising.

Comment: Thanks for the Notes. To me, "Equi" is more antique than classic, and "Noun equivalent" is a broad term.

Answer (score 1):

In **Elements of Symbolic Logic**, Hans Reichenbach gives this example of a predicate which is a quantified argument of another predicate: "Napoleon had all the qualities of a great general."  This wording should make Reichenbach's point clear: (For all P)(if P is predicated of a great general then P is predicated of Napoleon).

Reichenbach calls the analysis of such propositions part of "the higher calculus of functions".  Or, I think one could term it "second order predicate logic".